# Footer won't go to the bottom

Tags: html, wrapper, footer, jsfiddle

I need some quick help. My footer simply won't go down at the end of the site.
It's inside the wrapper and so on.
I simply can't find the error (looking at the same code to long time)

I've put the code into Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heNuB/

Don't mind the other codes, I've marked the footer with background-color:black; so you can see where the footer is trying to go.
It's trying to get in "behind" my 3 boxes.

Hope some of you have the time to look into it. I know that it's a bit of a noobish problem.

Good day to you all! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a clearing div right before the footer and it should go to the bottom.

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Your floated boxes are pushing past the main wrapper.

For reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked.
I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `clear: both;`

```
footer
{
    font-size:small;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
    clear: both;

}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Sudjy/

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just increase the margin-top attribute this is my code:

```
  .footer {
background-color: #717164;
margin-top: 50px;  
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
width:99%;
height: 10%;
position: fixed;
clear: both;
margin-top: 565px;
}
```

the .footer is because I gave my footer div a class of footer incase you didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you give the footer a margin-top property
.footer
{
    margin-top: 50px; //or something
 }
it should go down.